# Cannot override onClick method

Tags: java, android

Android Studio is telling me that I am not overriding my onClick method. I specified the onClick method in the Activity.xml file with:

```
android:onClick="onClickBerechnen"
```

what am I doing wrong?

```
public static final String BETRAG_KEY = "betrag";
public static final String BETRAG_ART = "art";
public static final String UST_PROZENT = "ust";

@Override
public void onClickBerechnen(View v) {


    final EditText txtBetrag = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_betrag);
    final float betrag = Float.parseFloat(txtBetrag.getText().toString());

    boolean isNetto = true;
    final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_art);
    switch (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.rb_art_netto: isNetto = true; break;
        case R.id.rb_art_brutto: isNetto = false; break;
        default:
    }

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_umsatzsteuer);
    final int pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    final int[] prozentwerte = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.ust_werte);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, ErgebnisActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(BETRAG_KEY, betrag);
    intent.putExtra(BETRAG_ART, isNetto);
    intent.putExtra(UST_PROZENT, prozentwerte);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Ah a real denglische Frage out of the code view.

Answer (score 3):

you need not to override that method. remove `@Override` and you are fine.

when you declare a method to be used at `onClick` of a view you just need to define that method in your respective activity class.

`@override` tag is used to denote overridden methods from your base class.

Comment: i removed @Override and the warning disappeared but my app is still crashing with npe when i am using the button

Comment: thats a different problem :) try checking your logs for npe your will find something.

Comment: google for your exception issue or post another question.

Answer (score 1):

The @Override annotation is only used when you want to override a method inherited from a superclass and replace it with your own method.

In your case, this is only a normal method called whenever the user clicks on the button, so you're not overriding any already existing "onClickBerechnen" method.

Answer (score 0):

For the me the situation looks like the following:
First debug where it actually crashes, showing just the log without actually saying where it crashes it does't help. 
Secondly, I think you must try to access your ids using

```
YouActivity.this.findViewById(id);
```

Next or first, be sure the view is actually the view you want:
check if:

```
view.getId==R.id.btn_id
```